# Import svg with gradient stroke to paper.js project

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, paperjs

Paper.js don't show path with gradient imported from SVG.

Here is an example https://codepen.io/Husband/pen/LoomQo
As you can see a path with stroke color `red` is displayed, and path with a gradient is hidden.

```
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="593" viewBox="0 0 1440 593" id="svg" style="display: none">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="a" x1="3.463%" y1="53.239%" y2="53.239%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2CC2FE" stop-opacity="0"/>
            <stop offset="49.904%" stop-color="#24C1FF"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#3AC6FE" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="curves" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".271">
        <path stroke="url(#a)" d="M.51 345.572s130.835 62.466 339.31 62.466c208.473 0 264.545-82.37 527.654-82.37 263.108 0 317.742 179.132 671.43 179.132" transform="translate(-81 25)"/>
        <path stroke="red" d="M.51 342.824s137.305 69.09 345.78 69.09c208.473 0 258.075-94.184 521.184-94.184 263.108 0 317.742 179.541 671.43 179.541" transform="translate(-81 25)"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
        var item = project.importSVG(document.getElementById('svg'));
        item.visible = true; 
        var group = item.children.curves;
        item.fitBounds(view.bounds);
        item.scale(2);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `paper.js` current SVG import implementation which doesn't follow SVG spec (`x2` default value should be `100%`).
I reported the [issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1660) and I will fix it soon.

As a workaround, you can set `x2` value to `100%` and this will work as expected.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) demonstrating the workaround.

```
const svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="593" viewBox="0 0 1440 593" id="svg" style="display: none">\n' +
    '    <defs>\n' +
    '        <linearGradient id="a" x1="3.463%" y1="53.239%" x2="100%" y2="53.239%">\n' +
    '            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2CC2FE" stop-opacity="0"/>\n' +
    '            <stop offset="49.904%" stop-color="#24C1FF"/>\n' +
    '            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#3AC6FE" stop-opacity="0"/>\n' +
    '        </linearGradient>\n' +
    '    </defs>\n' +
    '    <g id="curves" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".271">\n' +
    '        <path stroke="url(#a)" d="M.51 345.572s130.835 62.466 339.31 62.466c208.473 0 264.545-82.37 527.654-82.37 263.108 0 317.742 179.132 671.43 179.132" transform="translate(-81 25)"/>\n' +
    '        <path stroke="red" d="M.51 342.824s137.305 69.09 345.78 69.09c208.473 0 258.075-94.184 521.184-94.184 263.108 0 317.742 179.541 671.43 179.541" transform="translate(-81 25)"/>\n' +
    '    </g>\n' +
    '</svg>';

var item = project.importSVG(svg);
item.visible = true;
var group = item.children.curves;
item.fitBounds(view.bounds);
item.scale(2);
```