# Import SVG to path in paper.js returns null

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

Upon trying to import an SVG into the paper.js canvas, the element logs as "null".

```
<script src="path/to/paper-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
<script src="path/to/script.js" type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas"></script>
```

inside `script.js`:

```
var svg = '../assets/couch.svg';

var couch = project.importSVG(svg);

console.log(couch); // returns null
```

I don't know why this isn't working, as this method seems to be used in solutions to different answers… -> [Import svg with gradient stroke to paper.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476565/import-svg-with-gradient-stroke-to-paper-js-project)

Expected output of `console.log` would be an object (see http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#importsvg-svg where it says "Returns:
Item — the newly created Paper.js item containing the converted SVG content")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right, it appears that you can only import and work with SVG files from the `importSVG()` callback. If you want to use it as an object outside the callback function, it needs to be a DOM element.

copy and paste the content of the SVG file "inline" into your html file, append it using the fetch API or echo its contents from the backend (which is what I ended up doing), then:

```
svg = document.getElementById('your-selector')

var yourConvertedSVGItem = project.importSVG(svg, function() {
    svg.style.display = 'none' // hide the source image or do something else here
})

console.log(yourConvertedSVGItem)
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the return value, you have to pass either a SVG DOM node or a SVG string. If you pass a URL, the return value can't be used right away because Paper.js has to load the file asynchronously.